# Symfony2 config.php troubles: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vendor-dir, Vendor libraries are missing, how to resolve?

Tags: php, symfony, config

today, after a while, I decided to create a new Symfony2 project. I have composer installed at `/usr/local/bin/composer` and it is updated to its latest version:

```
$ composer self-update
You are already using composer version etc, etc...
```

Then I have typed the usual command:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/to/htdocs/PDFMonitor
```

All went good:

```
...
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Trying to install assets as symbolic links.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
```

Then I opened the browser and made a request to the symfony's `config.php` to be sure that actually everything was smooth, but I got this Major Problem error:

[image: Symfony2 config.php]

And this PHP notice and warning:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vendor-dir in /path/to/htdocs/PDFMonitor/app/SymfonyRequirements.php on line 751

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vendor-dir in /path/to/htdocs/PDFMonitor/app/SymfonyRequirements.php on line 751

Warning: file_get_contents(/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/skeleton/app/SymfonyRequirements.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/htdocs/PDFMonitor/app/SymfonyRequirements.php on line 546
```

I do not know why this is happening. I didn't use Symfony for a while, but I never had such a problem.

What I tried:

- Run either `composer install` and `composer update` inside the project's root. Didn't help.
- Reinstall composer `curl -s https://getcomposer/installer | php` and then:

  > $ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin
  >
  > $ rm -R /path/to/htdocs/PDFMonitor`

  and again:

  > $ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/to/htdocs/PDFMonitor

  Again the project is created but opening `http://localhost/PDFMonitor/web/config.php` gave the previous errors.

As I said I never experienced this problem before.

What should I do in order to make symfony work properly again? Why Symfony doesn't see the vendors?

Comment: Have you tried to go into root dir of symfony app and run `composer install`

Comment: Yes I have done it without any effort as you can read from my question. I have just found that the issue is a bug of Symfony2.6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744855/symfony-2-6-error-after-using-composer-vendor-libraries-must-be-installed#answer-27745261 But I still cannot get rid of these annoying error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem: this is a bug in Symfony 2.6, actually 2.7 seem to have fixed it.

If someone still creates a project with `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ...`, where the Symfony2 version defaults to 2.6 and experiences the same problem I have faced, here is a workaround:

Either edit `YourProject/app/SymfonyRequirements.php` **line 406** and

`YourProject/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/skeleton/app/SymfonyRequirements.php` **line 406** and replace:

```
 is_dir($this->getComposerVendorDir()),
```

With this:

```
is_dir(__DIR__.'/../vendor/composer'),
```

This will remove the Major Problem complaining about the vendors. Then this will instead remove the `file_get_contents()` Warning:

Inside `YourProject/app/SymfonyRequirements.php` and make **line 546** look like this:

```
file_get_contents(__FILE__) === file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/skeleton/app/SymfonyRequirements.php'),
```

Then open `localhost/YourProject/web/config.php` and you will see the nice Symfony Welcome page again.

[image]